# Find out which file a process is writing when PID changes all the time

Tags: chromium, disk-usage

Using tools like iotop one can monitor the i/o of individual processes which is fine, but you do not find out which directory a process writes into.
If the PID would always be the same that would not be a problem, one could strace or something else to find out which files are affected, or possibly

```
lsof +p <PID>
```

But I noticed chromium does some heavy disk writes when I open a video, despite the fact that I already put many directories associated with chromium on a tmpfs. 
Now I would like to find out which directories it writes to in the instant iotop shows the high i/o usage. 
Chromium does change the PID all the time, which makes this even more complex.

Comment: What about running `strace chromium`? Not sure if that will include the sub-processes launched for the tabs but it might help.

Answer (score 2):

We may use [`pidof`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pidof) to determine the PID(s) of an application for [`iotop`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/iotop) [image: Install iotop]

```
sudo iotop -p $(pidof chromium-browser | sed -r 's/[ ]+/ -p /g')
```

For any other command needing a different separator of the PID list replace the separator in the `sed` command, e.g.

```
top -p $(pidof chromium-browser | sed -r 's/[ ]+/,/g')
sudo lsof -p $(pidof chromium-browser | sed -r 's/[ ]+/,/g')
```

Comment: pidof chromium-browser is empty :-(, despite chromium-browser running. 
In iotop chromium command looks like this: chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=~82, --enable-pinch

Comment: What release version are you? IIRC Chromium processes may now have different names dependent on roles. See `ps aux | grep chromium`.

Answer (score 1):

The new utility **fatrace** can show you this. See: https://launchpad.net/fatrace/

```
sudo fatrace
```

For example:

```
# sudo fatrace
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.config/google-chrome/Default/Current Session
chrome(6514): R /home/xxxx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
chrome(6516): R /home/xxxx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
chrome(6516): RW /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_0
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
wicd(29613): RO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
ifconfig(29613): R /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
ifconfig(29613): CO /etc/ld.so.cache
```