# Almost never ending disk access

Tags: disk, 19.10

I use Ubuntu 19.10 on Lenovo G550, sometimes never-ending disk access starts and blocks mouse/keyboard input for almost 10 minutes. I don't have much apps or tabs open.
Is there a solution?
TIA

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/450613/find-out-which-file-a-process-is-writing-when-pid-changes-all-the-time and https://askubuntu.com/q/504145/197910